# peewee ORM: select function()

Tags: python, peewee

I have a query, which contains a part like this:

```
WHERE value IN (SELECT function_call())
```

Which I see as:

```
.where(Model.value << ???)
```

But I'm stuck on `SELECT function_call()`. How can I write it using peewee?

Answer (score 0):

```
from peewee import fn
fn.SOME_SQL_FUNCTION()
```

So:

```
query = MyModel.select().where(MyModel.value.in_(fn.some_sql_func()))
```

If the function takes parameters you can pass them as you would normally.